# how to remove .apk file from android market?

Tags: android, google-play

I updated an application, I have to remove the existing application and put it in place of the existing as my client said. 
My question is: How to remove an android application from android Market which uploaded before some days?

Comment: Do you want to put a new updated version up?

Comment: no i just wanna delete the existing and want to put it as 1st version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

unpublish it from your google developer account and your application will not appear on market.